# Need to solve issue with building Icecast client for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, server, audio-streaming, icecast

Few days ago, I've built icecast server on my local and built static library for iOS with libshout to build icecast client on iOS. (XCode7.0).

When I built static library, it support armv7, armv7s, armv64 (Build Active Architecture Only : False).

So I got libaudiostream.a.

Then I am going to use this library for iOS development.

When I use this library, I got following error when init this library.

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

"__shout_httpp_parse_response", referenced from:

```
  _parse_http_response in libaudiostream.a(shout.o)
```

"__shout_httpp_getvar", referenced from:

```
  _parse_http_response in libaudiostream.a(shout.o)
```

"__shout_sock_write_bytes", referenced from:

```
  _try_write in libaudiostream.a(shout.o)
```

"__shout_sock_recoverable", referenced from:

```
  _try_write in libaudiostream.a(shout.o)

  _get_response in libaudiostream.a(shout.o)
```

"__shout_sock_read_bytes", referenced from:

```
  _get_response in libaudiostream.a(shout.o)
```

"__shout_sock_connected", referenced from:

```
  _try_connect in libaudiostream.a(shout.o)
```

"__shout_httpp_destroy", referenced from:

.....

My static library support armv7 and armv64, too.

I checked it with nm on terminal.

00001538 t _updateStats

libaudiostream.a(shout.o) (for architecture armv7):

```
     U ___memcpy_chk

     U ___sprintf_chk

     U ___stack_chk_fail

     U ___stack_chk_guard

     U ___udivdi3

     U ___vsnprintf_chk
```

00006584 b __initialized

```
     U __shout_httpp_create_parser

     U __shout_httpp_destroy

     U __shout_httpp_getvar

     U __shout_httpp_initialize

     U __shout_httpp_parse_response

     U __shout_sock_close

     U __shout_sock_connect_non_blocking

     U __shout_sock_connect_wto

     U __shout_sock_connected

     U __shout_sock_error

     U __shout_sock_initialize

     U __shout_sock_read_bytes

     U __shout_sock_recoverable

     U __shout_sock_shutdown

     U __shout_sock_write

     U __shout_sock_write_bytes

     U __shout_timing_get_time

     U __shout_timing_sleep

     U __shout_util_base64_encode

     U __shout_util_dict_free

     U __shout_util_dict_get

     U __shout_util_dict_new

     U __shout_util_dict_set
```

.....

So, My question is that is there any additional change required for building lib for supporting arm64 & armv7 or i did any mistake in above step.

Please current me if i am wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Solved myself. It was my mistake.

Comment: did you get the libshout library working with iOS? I'm trying the exact same thing and experience some problems. I had the same problem like you but it seems that for armv7 it is now working, at least I don't get any build errors. But I am not able to connect to the icecast server. Any advice?

Comment: I already solved this issue and built icecast client for iOS.

Comment: you can get full library and ios icecast client (objective-c) on my github account. [link](https://github.com/gstream)

Comment: @gstream79 I need to build icecast client for iOS. Can you please provide some help? Thanks is advance.

Comment: @Punita, what is your issue?

Comment: @gstream79, how to connect Icecast server in objective-c and send audio file in particular time interval.

Comment: please check full source code of icecast client in my github.

Comment: if you have any questions after check source code, send me your questions via my email.

Comment: @gstream79 hey, can I chat with you regarding Icecast client for ios? actually, I want the Icecast client for ios. do you have any reference?

Comment: @PremalKhetani, you can check my repo - https://github.com/gstream/iOS-Icecast-Client

Comment: @gstream79  were you able  to get libshout to build for iOS using the existing ./configure script?     I can't seem to get it to produce an arm64 build.